# How to register a listener for orientation change?

Tags: java, android, orientation

My android app will run at background and I need to be notify immediately when orientation change. eg. When user rotate the phone from portrait to landscape (or landscape to portrait), the system should be tell my app that the orientation has changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This method is called when screen rotated

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Does this method will be call if my app hasn't been started? What I really need is that my app wake up (or start) when orientation change.

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: I have read these before I post the question. They said that "Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your activity is running."  So, the method will not be call if my app isn't running. Is there any solution for me?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh Do you solved it? I have the same problem now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to explicitly set the Orientation listener.

`onConfigurationChanged` will be called by the system.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
    int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    switch(orient) {
                case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
                case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
                default:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can implement onConfigurationChanged in daemon. 
here : [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).